# php mysql insert and update

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

Hy there, I guess I've tried everything I could. Somehow my form doesn't work. 
I get an ID through the URL  - Which I try to use to update the MySQL table

I use the same Form also to input a new Record and there is no problem. But to update it doesn't work at all.

```
if (true !=$fehler)
{
if ($clientid == 'new')
    {
        $qy = 'INSERT INTO tbl_clientdb (
                 clientid,
                 c_update,
                 c_Uupdate,
                 c_Gender,
                 c_IDNumber,
                 c_Name,
                 c_Firstname,
                 c_Middlename,
                 c_idCity,
                 c_idCountry,
                 c_idLanguage,
                 c_Phone,
                 c_Cellphone,
                 c_Email,
                 c_Note,
                 c_idCompany
               )
               VALUES (
                 NULL,
                 NOW(),
                 "'.$c_Uupdate.'",
                 "'.$c_Gender.'",
                 "'.$c_IDNumber.'",
                 "'.$c_Name.'",
                 "'.$c_Firstname.'",
                 "'.$c_Middlename.'",
                 "'.$c_idCity.'",
                 "'.$c_idCountry.'",
                 "'.$c_idLanguage.'",
                 "'.$c_Phone.'",
                 "'.$c_Cellphone.'",
                 "'.$c_Email.'",
                 "'.$c_Note.'",
                 "'.$c_idCompany.'"
               )';
    } else  {
$qy = 'UPDATE 
            tbl_clientdb
        SET
            c_update        = NOW(),
            c_Uupdate       = "'.$c_Uupdate.'",
            c_Gender        = "'.$c_Gender.'",
            c_IDNumber      = "'.$c_IDNumber.'",
            c_Name          = "'.$c_Name.'",
            c_Firstname     = "'.$c_Firstname.'",
            c_Middlename    = "'.$c_Middlename.'",
            c_idCity        = "'.$c_idCity.'",
            c_idCountry     = "'.$c_idCountry.'",
            c_idLanguage    = "'.$c_idLanguage.'",
            c_Phone         = "'.$c_Phone.'",
            c_Cellphone     = "'.$c_Cellphone.'",
            c_Email         = "'.$c_Email.'",
            c_Note          = "'.$c_Note.'",
            c_idCompany     = "'.$c_idCompany.'"
        WHERE 
            clientid    = '.$clientid.'
        LIMIT 1';
}
if ($res = mysql_query($qy))
    {
        echo 'Your data has been saved successfully';
    }
else 
    {
    echo mysql_error();
    $meld = 'Please try again';
    }
}`
```

anybody an idee what could be the trouble?

thx a lot for any inputs.

Comment: `echo $query` and paste that into phpmyadmin. it will give you your error. It's hard for anyone to help here since there is no context as to what your variables equal.

Comment: _'it doesn't work'_ is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated so you should be using PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: mysql_query() returning non-false on an update query doesn't mean the update was successful. It just means it ran. You'd need to check "affected rows" to see if anything actually got changed. remember: an empty result set is **NOT** an error. it's a successful query that happen to return/change nothing.

Comment: Have you made the client database yourself? If so your ID field should auto increment therefor trying to add a NULL valur to and ID field could be problematic.   Try to skip the client ID field when inserting just like you did with the UPDATE     Skip the clientid field and its Null value in your INSERT statement

Answer (score 0):

```
    $qy = 'SELECT
             clientid,
             c_update,
             c_Uupdate,
             c_Gender,
             c_IDNumber,
             c_Name,
             c_Firstname,
             c_Middlename,
             c_idCity,
             c_idCountry,
             c_idLanguage,
             c_Phone,
             c_Cellphone,
             c_Email,
             c_Note,
             c_idCompany

FROM tablename WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($yourConnection, $qy) or die (mysqli_error());
While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

/* Create a variable to hold all the data */

$c_update = $row['c_update'];

/* Do same for the rest */
}
Mysqli_free_result($query);
?>
```

Hope this helps